# Is there a way to use a number array to reduce the amount of code

Tags: jquery

Well i'm facing a problem with jQuery. I'm trying to make a gallery and I have this code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="image" id="img">
</div>

<div id="thumbnails">
    <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb1">
    <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb2">
    <img src="img/thumb3.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb3">
    <img src="img/thumb4.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb4">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#thumb1').click(function(){
           $('#img').attr("src","img/1.jpg");
        });
        $('#thumb2').click(function(){
           $('#img').attr("src","img/2.jpg");
        });
        $('#thumb3').click(function(){
           $('#img').attr("src","img/3.jpg");
        });
        $('#thumb4').click(function(){
           $('#img').attr("src","img/4.jpg");
        });
    });
```

Works great but, if I have more than 4 images, let's say... 40 images, it's a lot of code. I wonder if there's a way to do this without writing all that code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a `class` instead of `id`. If all your images are going to be numbered like in the question, you can have a `data-id` attribute to contain that value. 
Something like this

```
<div id="thumbnails">
    <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb1" class="thumb" data-id="1">
    <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb2" class="thumb" data-id="2">
    <img src="img/thumb3.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb3" class="thumb" data-id="3">
    <img src="img/thumb4.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb4" class="thumb" data-id="4">
</div>

$('.thumb').on('click', function(){
  $(this).attr('src', 'img/' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '.jpg');
});
```

As Mr. T.J.Crowder suggests in comments below, the implementation is up to you. Store the value in `data-id` or just use `id`. But finally use a `class` for all images so that you can have only a single click event attached instead of multiple.

Comment: When it comes to `data` attributes, jquery provides a better method `data()` to access these properties. `$(this).data("id")`

Comment: @SterlingArcher: If all you're doing is getting the value, it's best to use `attr`, not `data`. `data` sets up a data cache for the element and initializes it from all of the `data-*` attributes on the element. It is **not** a simple accessor for `data-*` attributes, it does much more work than that. And it never *writes* to them (just to the data cache).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder really? I didn't know that. Sauce?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder neither did I :|

Comment: Of course, if you're going to leave the `id`s on the elements, you could just use the `id` and strip off the "thumb" prefix: `this.id.substring(5)`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add another attribute with location to big image, e.g.

```
<div id="thumbnails">
    <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" data-big="img/1.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb1">
    <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" data-big="img/2.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb2">
    <img src="img/thumb3.jpg"  data-big="img/3.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb3">
    <img src="img/thumb4.jpg"  data-big="img/4.jpg" alt="thumbnail" id="thumb4">
</div>
```

and then use jQuery

```
$('#thumbnails img').click(function(){ 
     $('#gallery img:first').attr('src',$(this).attr('data-big')); 
});
```